# Managing multiple branches with Git when there are multiple PRs in progress

Tags: git

If I've got a couple of branches that are in PR status and I want to create a new branch so I can start working on a new feature, how do I do that? Do I create the new branch off the latest of the most recent branch that is in PR status?

Both PRs have not been merged into master, so I think if I just create a branch it might not pick up the latest code that is in my latest PR.

Or do I need to bug my reviewers to get my PR reviewed and merged quickly, is that the better route?

Comment: please do not close this.  This is a question that's based on a unique scenario, there is no code example for this

Comment: You could branch off a branch if you need the non-merged changes in the first branch. However, that is risky - if the first branch fails PR and gets held up, then the second branch will be delayed as well. As much as possible, try to take all your feature branches from your mainline.

Comment: "Or do I need to bug my reviewers to get my PR reviewed and merged quickly, is that the better route?" That is the best route in my opinion.

Comment: thanks all!!  helped a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky question, and one which I have encountered frequently over the years.  If the next task you want to begin is dependent on the work contained in either branch which is in PR, then you might want to wait until those PRs have been completed.  If you branch off one (or both) of the PR branches, you run the risk of some of your new work being invalidated later on should you need to make substantial changes to the PR branches as part of the review process.

If you can begin new work off the main topic branch, then this might be the easiest way to go.  Once the PRs have been completed, you can consider those tasks which are dependent on the changes.  If you absolutely must continue the work begun on either PR branch, then perhaps you can hound the reviewers and ask them to expedite the review.

Ideally your workflow should avoid this situation from happening in the first place, but I gave a couple of options to consider.

Comment: yea I bugged them, but really don't have a choice I guess but to create a new branch off the latest unreviewed PR :(

Comment: plus I'm the new guy so tactfully bugging people :)